# Grab file from chrome webRequest onBeforeRequest

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest, form-data

I am trying to fetch the files that want to be uploaded via POST.
Unfortunately i only get the requestBody as FormData giving me huge headaches accessing the file. I only get the filename as string.... I would like to have the file contents as blob or data-url...

```
//in a form on a page
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>

//extension's background.js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( function(details) {
    console.log(details);
    n = "files[]";
    var file = details.requestBody.formData[n][0];
    console.log(file ); // BabyGnuTux-Big.jpg
    console.log(typeof file); // string
},
  {urls: ["*://example.de/*"]},
  ["blocking", "requestBody"]);
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`details.requestBody.raw`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#property-details-requestBody)? (e.g., `details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes` should be an `ArrayBuffer`, if `raw` is defined)

Comment: requestBody.raw is not provided, if FormData is provided. FormData is always provided, if possible.

Comment: Is there a wa to "damage" form so that they will not get parsed to formdata?

Comment: can i send it to a nativeClient localhost to get the data?